# Typological frequency of sound changes; the case of s > h sound change

Tags: phonology, historical-linguistics, indo-aryan

I was wondering how can I  infer the typological "frequency" of given sound changes? How can I find out how typical is a given sound change typologically? Is there a *catalogue* of attested sound changes with their estimated typological frequency?

Particularly, the  *s > *h sound change in Proto-Iranian has intrigued me. I have read that this is a *typical* sound change from a typological point of view. However, I could not find papers discussing the *frequency* of this sound change.

Thanks very much,

Comment: I don’t think it’s really possible to calculate actual frequency. I suppose you could (theoretically) gather all observed or posited sound changes in all known stages of all known languages in the world and then simply express the frequency as the number of times a particular change appears divided by the total number of changes in the data set… but then you also need to start out by defining what constitutes a unique sound change. For example, Middle English /iː/ has become Modern English /aɪ/ – is that one change, or is it actually five (/iː/ → /ij/ → /ɪj/ → /əj/ → /ʌj/ → /aɪ/)?

Comment: And what if there’s another language where /iː/ has become /aɪ/, but via a different path, such as /iː/ → /eː/ → /eɪ/ → /aɪ/? Would those two language share a sound change or not? The most precise we can say is that something which was at one point /s/ having at a later point changed into /h/ has been observed in lots of different languages (Iranian, Sanskrit, Ancient Greek, Welsh, Irish, currently happening in Spanish, etc.). That makes it valid enough to call it a typologically common change, even if we can’t necessarily quantify such statements with any tangible frequencies.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: Thanks for your illuminating comments. Regarding to your first comment I do agree with you. Yes, the sound change is first to be defined precisely. Regarding to your second comment, I understand your point. What you mentioned is what I yearn for! That is a paper which demonstrates the "commonness" of this particular sound change based on statistics. Thank you again.